# Carthagenet error when trying to import a snapshot

Tags: node, snapshots, carthagenet

I'm currently trying to setup a **Carthagenet** node from the snapshot on https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/ with the **Docker** mode.

But when I want to run the command `carthagenet.sh snapshot import /home/ec2-user/carthagenet_2020-07-05.rolling` (I renamed the snapshot file), I got the following error :

```
$ carthagenet.sh snapshot import /home/ec2-user/carthagenet_2020-07-05.rolling
v7.2: Pulling from tezos/tezos
Digest: sha256:c38c260bc498f712a1dde5cd16d0e9cff102cd7c365fec2d6c48674ff2fed785
Status: Image is up to date for tezos/tezos:v7.2
docker.io/tezos/tezos:v7.2
carthagenet_importer_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to carthagenet_importer_1
importer_1                    | Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
importer_1                    | Removing outdated chain data...
importer_1                    | tezos-node: Error:
importer_1                    |               Specified --network has chain name
importer_1                    |               TEZOS_ALPHANET_CARTHAGE_2019-11-28T13:02:13Z, but current configuration
importer_1                    |               implies expected chain name TEZOS_MAINNET. Use:
importer_1                    |               tezos-node config init --network <NETWORK> to configure your node.
importer_1                    |
```

I have try to run the command `tezos-node config init --network carthagenet` by using it directly with `docker run` but this is not working.

I just follow the documentation at https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/snapshots.html#importing-a-snapshot and https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html and my carthagenet.sh script is from the https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/raw/latest-release/scripts/tezos-docker-manager.sh.

Did I miss something on the setup of the rolling node ? Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few try, I have found a solution of the problem.

You need to run (in this order):

1 - `carthagenet.sh node start --history-mode experimental-rolling` to start a not up-to-date node.

2 -  `carthagenet.sh snapshot import /home/ec2-user/carthagenet_2020-07-05.rolling` in a second time.

The snapshot will be imported during the run of the node.

I suppose the error was due to a missing `config.json` file in the docker volumes used by the node (and shared by the importer) which is generated when the node run for the first time.

I hope it will help.